Some confusion about page 186 in stein's real analysis
In page 186, the author declared that for diagonalized linear transformation T, if $f$ ~ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \varphi _k$, then $Tf$ ~ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \lambda_k \varphi _k$.
My first question is that does the signal "~" mean approximation? Namely the distance of LHS between RHS can be arbitrarily small. But without the condition that "T is bounded", can we get this result?
My second question is that how can we prove that $T^*$ corresponds to the sequence {$\bar \lambda_k$}?

See page 171 ;-)

OK, if $f$ ~ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \varphi _k$, it means that $(f, \varphi _k ) = a_k$. But how can we prove that $(Tf, \varphi _ k) = a_k \lambda _k$?
